# ggplot: shaping data for a scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapes

I have a data frame like the following (imagine multiple markets, 1 Market: 2 variables):

```
 Market    Variables  median  lower.limit  upper.limit
 market_1   var_1      2.78    2.71         2.72
 market_1   var_2      3.21    2.96         3.44
 market_2   var_1      2.95    2.79         3.11
 market_2   var_2      2.11    1.91         2.30
```

I would like to do a scatter plot with whiskers of the data (var_1 vs var_2), but I'm having trouble understanding how to reshape the data.  I think the data frame needs to go from long to wide form, but I'm not sure what to do with the lower/upper limits in the transformation.  Would my columns be:

```
  Market    var_1    var_1_lower.limit   var_1_upper.limit    var_2_median    var_2_lower.limit    var_2.upper.limit
```

Or is there a way to basically subset my data directly with ggplot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reshape the data to `wide` form, you can use `reshape` from `base R`

```
reshape(df, idvar="Market", timevar='Variables', direction='wide')
#    Market median.var_1 lower.limit.var_1 upper.limit.var_1 median.var_2
#1 market_1         2.78              2.71              2.72         3.21
#3 market_2         2.95              2.79              3.11         2.11
#  lower.limit.var_2 upper.limit.var_2
#1              2.96              3.44
#3              1.91              2.30
```

Or using `dplyr/tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    gather(Var, Val, median:upper.limit) %>% 
    unite(VarN,Variables, Var, sep="_") %>%
    spread(VarN, Val)

#    Market var_1_lower.limit var_1_median var_1_upper.limit var_2_lower.limit
#1 market_1              2.71         2.78              2.72              2.96
#2 market_2              2.79         2.95              3.11              1.91
#   var_2_median var_2_upper.limit
#1         3.21              3.44
#2         2.11              2.30
```

Or using `dcast/melt` from `reshape2`

```
 library(reshape2)
 dcast(melt(df, id=c("Market", "Variables")), Market~..., value.var='value')
 #         Market var_1_median var_1_lower.limit var_1_upper.limit var_2_median
 #1 market_1         2.78              2.71              2.72         3.21
 #2 market_2         2.95              2.79              3.11         2.11
 #  var_2_lower.limit var_2_upper.limit
 #1              2.96              3.44
 #2              1.91              2.30
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Market = c("market_1", "market_1", "market_2", 
"market_2"), Variables = c("var_1", "var_2", "var_1", "var_2"
), median = c(2.78, 3.21, 2.95, 2.11), lower.limit = c(2.71, 
2.96, 2.79, 1.91), upper.limit = c(2.72, 3.44, 3.11, 2.3)), .Names = c("Market", 
"Variables", "median", "lower.limit", "upper.limit"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Appreciate you providing the various methods.

Answer (score 1):

Another method of using reshape2:

```
library(reshape2)
mm = melt(ddf, id=c('Market',"Variables"))
dcast(mm, Market~Variables+variable)
    Market var_1_median var_1_lower.limit var_1_upper.limit var_2_median var_2_lower.limit var_2_upper.limit
1 market_1         2.78              2.71              2.72         3.21              2.96              3.44
2 market_2         2.95              2.79              3.11         2.11              1.91              2.30
```

But you do not need to reshape to have errorbars etc:

```
ggplot(ddf)+geom_errorbar(aes(x=Variables, y=median, ymin=lower.limit, ymax=upper.limit, color=Market))+geom_point(aes(x=Variables, y=median, color=Market))
```

[image]